# How do you control the auto-resize width for v-navigation-bar?

Tags: vuetify.js

A `clipped` `app` `v-navigation-bar` reverts to the non-clipped behavior when the browser width is a certain size, such that it hovers above the `v-app-bar` and becomes closable.

I actually do want this behavior for a more reactive experience on smaller displays, so I don't want to use `disable-resize-watcher`, but I disagree with the browser width threshold at which this behavior is engaged.

Is there a way to customize the threshold?

Thanks!

Example: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/google-youtube

Comment: Can you create a codepen to reprodcue this issue. That would be much easier to solve your issue

Comment: I'm apparently too thick to sort out Codepen with Vuetify but here's an example from Vuetify's website:

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/examples/layouts/google-youtube

Code: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/layouts/layouts/demos/google-youtube.vue

Comment: Is there any solution with Vuetify 3 now? :D